# HTML Form Submission - Validation - Losing 'buttonType' value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with 2 buttons that both submit. I need to track which button the user clicked to perform different actions. I've added a validation script to one of the buttons to check they have made some selections from the table, but this option appears to remove the button type that the user has selected. It doesn't appear in the POST request data that is processed on form submission.

Here's the buttons and the script that runs for the first button:

```js
$("#saveSelected").click(function(e) {
  // put your validation here
  if ($('#selectedAssetIDs').val() == '') {

    $("#selectedAssetIDsError").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#buttonType').val('createSelectedShipments');
    $("form").submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="createShipments" action="createShipments.php" method="post" role="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="createStaffShipments">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedAssetIDs" id="selectedAssetIDs" value="">


  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="createSelectedShipments" id="saveSelected" class="btn btn-success">Create Shipments - Selected</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="createAllShipments" id="saveAll" class="btn btn-success">Create Shipments - All</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  </div>

</form>
```

When I click the 2nd button it just submits the form and I can see the:

```
$_POST['buttonType']
```

value in the PHP page it submits to, but when the 1st button is clicked there is no `$_POST['buttonType']` value.

Comment: you are using a `#buttonType` selector, but I see no input with an ID 'buttonType'. Did you mean `[name="buttonType]` ?

Comment: @Derlin yes name="buttonType" - I'm after the value for that.

Comment: have you tried `$('[name=buttonType]').val('createSelectedShipments');` ?

Comment: post your complete form

Comment: Agree with @ewwink

Comment: @ewwink I've just added the form. There are no real inputs on this form as it's only submitting a hidden input that is set via Javascript for the first button. The 2nd button branches off to perform a different action.

Comment: both button generate value as expected (non empty)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6yNo.gif

Comment: The first button doesn't submit the form directly - it runs the script which validates that there is a hidden input value and then the script submits the form. Can I add to the script that submits the form another input value?

Comment: @Derlin yes I tried that but didn't get anything in the $_POST['buttonType'] when the form was submitted

Comment: This appears to work:

    `$(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="buttonType" value="createSelectedShipments" /> ');`